# What permissions are required for scp

Tags: linux, file-permissions

Google fails me. What are the permissions I need to set for a file to make it `scp`-able from somewhere? I thought read access is enough, but although I can secure-copy the file with my account, my collaborators cannot download the file `test` with `scp username@host.com:/path/to/test test`

```
 $ ls -aln

 drwxrwxrwx 3 15016 200     2048 Jul  8 13:35 .
 drwxrwxrwx 3 15016 200     2048 Jul  6 18:02 ..
 -rwxr-xr-x 1 15016 200        0 Jul  8 13:35 test
```

Comment: `rwx` for other seems a bit suspicius (but unrelated to the issue). Could you show permissions for all intermediate folders? I guess one of them is missing `x` for your collaborators. Please also include the error message your collaborators get.

Comment: ok so all intermediate folders need `+x`? I'll try it. The error is just the standard permission denied error